# $|f''(x)|\leq M$ implies $|f(c)-f(a)-(c-a)\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}|\leq \frac{1}{8} M(b-a)^2$

Tags: problem-solving

I am stuck with this problem.

> $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is double differentiable on $[a,b]$ and suppose $|f''(x)|\leq M ~ \forall x \in [a,b]$. Let $c \in (a,b)$. Then $|f(c)-f(a)-(c-a)\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}|\leq \frac{1}{8} M(b-a)^2$

I can prove this when the upper bound is $M(b-a)^2$.

> $|f(c)-f(a)-(c-a)\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}|=|c-a| |\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}|$. This equals $|c-a||\frac{f'(\xi_1)-f'(\xi_2)}{\xi_1-\xi_2}||\xi_1-\xi_2|$ for some $\xi_1\in (a,c)$ and $\xi_2 \in (a,b)$. This equals $|c-a||f''(\psi)||\xi_1-\xi_2|\leq (b-a)^2M$

Although I know this is weak and I haven't exploited the $\xi '$s fully. I cannot find the solution afterer lots of tries, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may want to try using Taylor's Theorem. (The link to the theorem FYR: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving inequation with maximum and 2nd derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2554480/proving-inequation-with-maximum-and-2nd-derivative) – you would apply it to $g(x) = f(x)-f(a)-(x-a)\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$.

Comment: I completely forgot to apply taylor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: The polynomial
$$
p(x)=f(a)+(x-a)\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}
$$
interpolates $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$.  What can you say about
$$
f(x)-p(x)-(f(\xi)-p(\xi))\cdot\frac{(x-a)(x-b)}{(\xi-a)(\xi-b)}?
$$

Comment: I dont know interpolates, anyway thanks